# number of consecutive months from the first communication

Tags: sql, sas, dataset

I wouold like to ask you for help with this problem.

I have list of customers and for each customer I have list of months in which this customer contacted us. I need to know in how many months a particular customer contacted us. But there is problem that I need to know only number of consecutive months from his first contact.

So I have table like this

```
+---------+-------+
| cust id | month |
+---------+-------+
|       1 | 2     |
|       1 | 3     |
|       1 | 4     |
|       1 | 5     |
|       1 | 8     |
|       1 | 9     |
|       1 | 10    |
|       1 | 11    |
|       1 | 12    |
+---------+-------+
```

And I need to add column like this

```
+---------+-------+-------+
| cust id | month | flg   |
+---------+-------+-------+
|       1 | 2     | 1     |
|       1 | 3     | 1     |
|       1 | 4     | 1     |
|       1 | 5     | 1     |
|       1 | 8     | 0     |
|       1 | 9     | 0     |
|       1 | 10    | 0     |
|       1 | 11    | 0     |
|       1 | 12    | 0     |
+---------+-------+-------+
```

So finally I only sum all 1 in column flg. The result will be that consumer 1 contacted us 4 times from his first contact consecutive.

I have tried use something like this but it does not work :( I do not know how to do that 1 will be only for fist consecutive line.

```
data test1;
 set customer_base;    
 retain month_ret;
 output;
 by cust_id month;
 month_ret = month;
 run;

 Data test2;
 Set test1;
 By cust_id;
 If first.cust_id then i=1;
 if month= month_ret+1 then i=1;
 if month<>month_ret+1 then output;
 Run;
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code.

1) `if month= month_ret+1 then i=1;`

every time that this is true, you set the flag to 1. However, you should only do this while this has never been false for the current customer.

2) `if month<>month_ret+1 then output;`

as you can see in the SAS log the `<>` operator is wrongly interpreted as `MAX`. Therefore, this condition is never true. Furthermore, because you have an explicit `output` here, if this condition were to be correctly written as `if month ne month_ret+1 then output;`, your resulting table would **only** contain records for which this condition is true.

What you are trying to achieve can be done in one step, like so:

```
   data have;
    infile datalines;
    input cust_id month;
    datalines;
    1 2
    1 3
    1 4
    1 5
    1 8
    1 9
    1 10
    1 11
    1 12
    ;
    run;

    data want (drop=p_month);
    set have;
    by cust_id;
    retain flg p_month;
    if first.cust_id then flg=1;
    else if month ne p_month+1 then flg=0;
    p_month=month;
    run;
```

For each first customer you set the flag to 1. Then whenever month is not equal to the previous plus one, you set the flag to 0.

Comment: It wors. Thank you very much!

Comment: user2877959, can you explain how does p _ month variable work in your example code?

Comment: @Alph I called the variable `p_month` for _"previous month"_, as in _"the value of month in the previous record"_. With the `retain` statement, I make sure that the value of `p_month` is retained accross iterations instead of being set to missing at the start of each as is the default behavior. At the end of each iteration, I assign the current value of `month` to `p_month`. Hence, during each iteration, `p_month` has the value of `month` from the previous record which allows me to compare the two.